# ElasticSearch service failing to start. Cannot find JVM

Tags: java, windows, elasticsearch

I have a fresh Windows Server 2012 and have installed the ElasticSearch service with `service install`.  When I try to start it though it fails to start (Exit code 1).

Looking at the logs it can't find the path to the JVM:

```
[2016-05-25 19:10:22] [info]  [ 1964] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2016-05-25 19:10:22] [info]  [ 1964] Starting service 'elasticsearch-service-x64' ...
[2016-05-25 19:10:22] [info]  [ 2508] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2016-05-25 19:10:22] [info]  [ 2508] Running 'elasticsearch-service-x64' Service...
[2016-05-25 19:10:22] [info]  [ 2968] Starting service...
[2016-05-25 19:10:22] [error] [ 2968] Failed creating java %JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2016-05-25 19:10:22] [error] [ 2968] The system cannot find the path specified.
[2016-05-25 19:10:22] [error] [ 2968] ServiceStart returned 1
[2016-05-25 19:10:22] [error] [ 2968] The system cannot find the path specified.
[2016-05-25 19:10:22] [info]  [ 2508] Run service finished.
[2016-05-25 19:10:22] [info]  [ 2508] Commons Daemon procrun finished
[2016-05-25 19:10:24] [error] [ 1964] Failed to start 'elasticsearch-service-x64' service
[2016-05-25 19:10:24] [error] [ 1964] The data area passed to a system call is too small.
[2016-05-25 19:10:24] [info]  [ 1964] Start service finished.
[2016-05-25 19:10:24] [error] [ 1964] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 5 (Failed to start service)
[2016-05-25 19:10:24] [error] [ 1964] The data area passed to a system call is too small.
```

However, the `JAVA_HOME` variable is set up correctly:

```
C:\elasticsearch-2.3.3\elasticsearch-2.3.3\bin>dir "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 6F6F-14E6

 Directory of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\bin\server

  05/25/2016  06:22 PM    <DIR>          .
  05/25/2016  06:22 PM    <DIR>          ..
  05/25/2016  06:22 PM        19,136,512 classes.jsa
  05/25/2016  06:21 PM         8,775,712 jvm.dll
  05/25/2016  06:21 PM             1,423 Xusage.txt
                 3 File(s)     27,913,647 bytes
                   2 Dir(s)  121,919,512,576 bytes free
```

I'm running the console as admin.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggest running `elasticsearch-service.bat manager`, go to the Java tab, and manually set the Java Virtual Machine location for jvm.dll.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just found the solution.  I moved the `JAVA_HOME` variable from user variables to system variables.

Now the service is running.

Comment: In our case, JAVA_HOME was already a system variable, but not updated after a Java update.

Answer (score 1):

When you’re using Maven on the same machine (i.e., Java developers), your `JAVA_HOME` **must** point to the **JDK home**, which has a `bin` directory but no subdirectory `server` with a `jvm.dll` in it. The file is in `jre\bin\server\jvm.dll` where it isn’t found.

Open a `cmd` window, change to the Elasticsearch directory, run `bin/elasticsearch-service manager`, go to “Java” tab and set the path to the `jvm.dll` correctly.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue even though JAVA_HOME is defined in the User variables still it needs to be defined in the System variables